# How to install and configure Postgres-XC in windows?

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering, postgresql-9.2, distributed-databases

Can anybody suggest me any resources of the complete installation procedure of postgres-XC in windows. I've installed postgresql-9.2 in my windows and can  use it. Now I need to know the installation procedure of postgre-XC and the way to do clustering and the whole distribution and replication process using postgres-XC. I've googled and found few but all of them are for linux. But I need this for windows.

FYI:

http://manojadinesh.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgres-xc-setup.html
http://alexalexander.blogspot.com/2013/01/postgres-xc-explained.html

Thanks

Comment: Clone of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16534109/398670. Please do not duplicate your posts, especially without linking between them. It wastes the time of people who're trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres-XC [does not run on Windows](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/):

> Postgres-XC currently runs on the Linux Operating Systems running on
>   64-bit Intel(R) processors.
>
> The development team tested this with Cent-OS 5.3 and 5.4.

You might be able to build the data nodes and possibly the coordinators on Windows, but the GTM will take major work to port to Windows.